# File transfer between AWS EC2 MVC app and Lambda Serverless Web API app results in corrupted data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, imagemagick

I have a MVC application which I am hosting on a Windows Server 2016 AWS EC2 instance. This application is an admin tool. This application uses a Web API application that is hosted as a AWS Lambda Serverless app (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-build-test-severless-app.html).

One area of my MVC app allows users to upload images using a form file input. This is then posted back to the MVC controller and sent off to an API utility which sends the file to the API. The API then resizes (using Magick.NET) and saves the image to an S3 bucket and the resulting URL to a MySQL database.

This all works perfectly when running locally on my machine. The problem is when I try to upload an image on the live website. The result is that when the image data is loaded into a MagickImage, I get the following error:

> ImageMagick.MagickCorruptImageErrorException: Not a JPEG file: starts
>   with 0xef 0xbf `' @ error/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/332\n

I added in some code to log the first 20 bytes of the data (which is a byte array) both in the MVC app (before the file is posted to the API) and in the API once the file was received. I discovered that the values I received were completely different, as shown below:

> - **MVC:** FF-D8-FF-E0-00-10-4A-46-49-46-00-01-01-01-01-2C-01-2C-00-00
> - **API:** EF-BF-BD-EF-BF-BD-EF-BF-BD-EF-BF-BD-00-10-4A-46-49-46-00-01

I then did the following when running locally and saw that the values outputted were the same:

> - **MVC:** FF-D8-FF-E0-00-10-4A-46-49-46-00-01-01-01-01-2C-01-2C-00-00
> - **API:** FF-D8-FF-E0-00-10-4A-46-49-46-00-01-01-01-01-2C-01-2C-00-00

Is there some sort of environment setting that I need to set/change which could be causing this strange behaviour?

Below are the different sections of code that are relevant, in order of occurrence.

**MVC controller:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddImage(ImageFormViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = viewModel.TourId, errors = string.Join(",", ViewData.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors.Select(y => y.ErrorMessage))) });
    }

    var apiResponse = await this.api.PostFile<ApiResponse>($"tours/{viewModel.TourId}/images", viewModel.Image);
    if (apiResponse.Success)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = viewModel.TourId, message = "Image added successfully!" });
    }
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = viewModel.TourId, errors = string.Join(",", apiResponse.Errors) });
    }
}
```

**API Utility (In MVC app):**

```
public async Task<TResponse> PostFile<TResponse>(string uri, IFormFile file) where TResponse : ApiResponse
{
    var response = default(TResponse);

    if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
    {
        var url = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uri) ? new Uri(new Uri(this.baseUrl), uri) : new Uri(this.baseUrl)).ToString();

        using (var http = new HttpClient())
        {
            byte[] data;
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                data = stream.ToArray();
            }

            this.logger.Information("First bytes (MVC app): " + BitConverter.ToString(data.Take(20).ToArray()));

            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(data), "file", file.FileName);

            var httpResponse = await http.PostAsync(url, content);
            response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
    }

    return response;
}
```

**API controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromRoute]string tourId)
{
    var response = new ApiResponse();
    if (Request.HasFormContentType)
    {
        var form = Request.Form;
        foreach (var formFile in form.Files)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                var result = await this.tourManagementService.AddImage(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(tourId), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(formFile.FileName), stream.ToArray());

                if (!result.Success)
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return Ok(response);
}
```

**Service method to save image etc:**

```
public async Task<AddImageResult> AddImage(string tourId, string imageName, byte[] imageData)
{
    this.logger.Information("First bytes (API): " + BitConverter.ToString(imageData.Take(20).ToArray()));

    ...
}
```

**Code where Magick.NET is used and exception is thrown:**

```
private byte[] resizeImage(byte[] imageData, int width, int height)
{
    using (var image = new MagickImage(imageData, new MagickReadSettings { Format = MagickFormat.Jpeg }))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: EF BF BD is the unicode replacement character � (U+FFFD) encoded in UTF-8. Perhaps some step read the file as if it were UTF8 and converted the non-ASCII characters to U+FFFD.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is the issue: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html

Answer (score 3):

The problem turned out to be that my AWS API Gateway wasn't accepting binary data. By default, API Gateway treats the message body as JSON as explained here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html

> By default, API Gateway treats the message body as a text payload and
>   applies any preconfigured mapping template to transform the JSON
>   string.

I believe the is the source of the corruption. To remedy this, I had to add "image/jpeg" as an accepted binary media type in API Gateway shown below:

[image]

I then adjusted my code to just deal with binary data (and scrapped the form content stuff):

**MVC side:**

```
public async Task<TResponse> PostFile<TResponse>(string uri, IFormFile file) where TResponse : ApiResponse
{
    var response = default(TResponse);

    if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
    {
        var url = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uri) ? new Uri(new Uri(this.baseUrl), uri) : new Uri(this.baseUrl)).ToString();

        using (var http = new HttpClient())
        {
            var content = new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream());
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType);

            var httpResponse = await http.PostAsync(url, content);
            response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
    }

    return response;
}
```

**API side:**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromRoute]string tourId)
{
    var response = new ApiResponse();
    if (Request.ContentType.Equals("image/jpeg"))
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(stream);

            ...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }

    return Ok(response);
}
```